# Why they depicted sex positions on temples?

Tags: temple

Why they depicted sex positions on temples?
we all know temples are considered as holy places, even footwear not allowed,
then Why they depicted sex positions on temples?
[image]

Comment: Err.. why do you assume sex is unholy?